# can I make an API request through google PHP API

Tags: php, api, rest, oauth

I'm talking about this: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/

Is it possible to use a method in that API library to send Oauth GET/POST requests in general...

I've been scanning the source code, and I can't seem to find any such method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to connect with? Adsense/Analytics/Gmail or what? All that code does is get you an Oauth key, all GET/POST requests are separated by which google application your are trying to connect with. The documentation can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/Samples)